# How can I get the port of my Rflink (Arduino Mega) to show in /dev on my Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, usb

I bought a RFlink Gateway from Nodo-shop.nl, the the RFLink 433.42 Somfy RTS version, to use with Domoticz on a RPI. I had Nodo to solder the components of my Rflink, so there should not be any problem on this end  :)

I connected it to my MacbookAir, and followed the instructions on Domoticz [wiki](https://www.domoticz.com/wiki/RFLink) to upload the firmware into the RFlink. It apparently uploaded the firmware successfully.

Then I updated and upgraded my RPI (Linux raspberrypi 5.4.79-v7+ #1373 SMP Mon Nov 23 13:22:33 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux) and hooked it up to my Raspberry Pi 3 .

I tried to identify the port with `Dmesg`. If the Arduino Mega is detected, I cannot see the `ttyAMCO` or `ttyUSB` everyone is referring to in various posts.

Here is the output of the `dmesg` command:

`[3902580.423329] usb 1-1.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg [3902580.568650] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 0.01 [3902580.568671] usb 1-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220 [3902580.568685] usb 1-1.1.2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc) [3902580.568699] usb 1-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 55037313237351714260`

I also tried to look for the port using this command `ls /dev | grep tty*`. I can only see these ports : `ttyXX, ttyAMA0 and ttyprintk`. But no sign of the port of my RFlink Gateway.

When I use this command `lsusb`, it shows it recognizes the Arduino:
`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2341:0042 Arduino SA Mega 2560 R3 (CDC ACM).`

I read tons of posts on the internet but I did not find any answer to my problem.

I even bought a power supply for my Arduino Mega as some wrote that it may not get enough power from the RPI's USB. But I still have the same problem...

What I'm not doing right ? Or what am I not looking at ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, bit late but it might be useful to someone else...

It might well be the /dev/ttyAMA0 you found - it depends what else you've got on there.

listing by id should identify it definitively though:

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18  2021 usb-0658_0200_12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012-if00 -> ../../ttyACM1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 18  2021 usb-Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0042_55639313533351509150-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
```

So, in my case it's on /dev/ttyACM0.

If you've got multiple USB serial adapters, reboot the pi with them all plugged in to get the default mapping (I've seen hotplugged AMA0 and AMA1 swap after a reboot).